# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\SpreadSheet" not found

Tags: php, composer-php, spreadsheet

when I use the project locally, the composer spreadsheet library works.
When I upload the project to a Digital Ocean ubuntu machine, I get this error:

> [Thu Oct 20 02:05:24.760534 2022] [php:error] [pid 817] [client 181.129.171.154:7921] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\SpreadSheet" not found in /var/www/Ausen2/logic/ausen_excel.php:16\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/Ausen2/logic/ausen_excel.php on line 16

the source code:

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';


use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\{SpreadSheet, IOFactory};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx; //Csv, Xls

require("../db.php");

session_start();
$sqli = $_SESSION['ausen_list'];

//$nombre_admin   = $_SESSION['NOM_USUARIO'];
//$id_admin = $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO'];


//excel file
$excel =new SpreadSheet();

$excel -> getProperties()->setCreator("Andres")->setTitle("Mi excel"); //metadatos
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  
$hojaActiva = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$hojaActiva->setTitle("Funcionarios");


//header information
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('A1','Cedula_Funcionario');  $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(15);    
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('B1','Fecha_Inicio');  $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);    
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('C1','Fecha_Fin');   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('D1','Tiempo');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('E1','Observación'); $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(20);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('F1','Seguridad_Trabajo');  $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(15);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('G1','ID_Usuario');     $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(15);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('H1','Tipo_Ausentismo');  $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(15);


$ausentismos = $conectar->query($sqli);

$fila = 2; 
while($ausentismo = $ausentismos->fetch_assoc()){
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $ausentismo['Cedula_F']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $ausentismo['Fecha_Inicio']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $ausentismo['Fecha_Fin']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $ausentismo['Tiempo']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $ausentismo['Observacion']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $ausentismo['Seguridad_Trabajo']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $ausentismo['ID_Usuario']);
        
    if($ausentismo['Tipo_Ausentismo'] == 1){
            $hojaActiva->setCellValue('H'.$fila, 'INCAPACIDAD');
    }elseif ($ausentismo['Tipo_Ausentismo'] == 2){
            $hojaActiva->setCellValue('H'.$fila, 'COMPENSATORIO');
    }elseif ($ausentismo['Tipo_Ausentismo'] == 3){
            $hojaActiva->setCellValue('H'.$fila, 'PERMISO');
    }elseif ($ausentismo['Tipo_Ausentismo'] == 4){
            $hojaActiva->setCellValue('H'.$fila, 'LICENCIA');
    }

    $fila++;
}

//save excel file

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Reporte.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Xlsx'); 
$writer->save('php://output');
exit; 
?>
```

i´ve already installed composer again, so the autoload file charge again. and i´ve used composer dump autoload.

SOLVED:
the problem was the name of the class, in my local environmet i use use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet{SpreadSheet, IOFactory} and it works, but when i installed this library in the server, the class name is Spreadsheet, with the lowercase s

Comment: Did you `composer install` to make sure the live machine has all the composer loaded libraries. In other words did you provision the live server?

Comment: yeah, i did provision the live server

Comment: I guess you are developing on windows then :) No problem with that but you do have to be aware that windows is case insensitive and linus is case sensitive.

Comment: _PS_ If you solve it, then write your own answer, dont put Solved in the question

Comment: yeah, i'm working on windows.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: the problem was the name of the class, in my local environmet i use use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet{SpreadSheet, IOFactory} and it works, but when i installed this library in the server, the class name is Spreadsheet, with the lowercase s